# Is there such a thing as "scanner.newLine();" that could read a console input multi-line paragraph?

Tags: java, text, methods, console, java.util.scanner

TLDR: I want to paste a multi-line paragraph into the console (to be used in a method) but due to .nextLine() it only puts the first line into a String variable and ignores the rest.

Hello everyone,
Im quite new to Java, and Im just finishing the very basics. Im still a bit bad with terminology. My task is a "Decrypter"-Method that takes an "encrypted" paragraph, swaps letters around in a method, and prints out the "decrypted" version: My decrypting-method works perfectly fine.

The problem is the User-Input: I need to put in an "encrypted" 7 line paragraph into the console, and it should return a "decrypted" 7 line paragraph. I have used scanner.nextLine(); which obviously doesnt work. As soon as there is a line break, the Scanner stops reading.
(Ive also noticed that if you CopyPaste a text/paragraph with multiple lines into the console, the console treats the first line break as an "Enter-Press")

I didnt really find any workaround that fits my problem. The ideal would be if there existed a scanner.newLine().
Again Im not very experienced and by now deeply confused and slightly frustrated :,D

First I tried removing the linebreaks by removing "\n" "\r" "\n\r" and replacing it with ""

```
String text = scanner.nextLine();
        text = text.replaceAll("\n","");
```

This didnt work because the initial input was only read until the first linebreak anyway, so there was nothing in "text" to be replaced.
I tried some shady Syntaxwork like "scanner.replaceAll("\n","").nextLine();" which was more an act of desperation.

There was this, which I really dont understand:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    scanner.useDelimiter("\n");
    scanner.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

Ive also found the "type how many lines you want to enter"-loop method, which works well, but that is not in the sense of the task.

Answer (score 1):

To give you the proper context, first an explanation of a few things:

`System.in` isn't actually the keyboard. It's "The process's standard input" which can be anything. It's merely 'whatever the user types' **by default**. For example, `java com.foo.MyApp <foo.txt` now sets up `System.in` to be the contents of the file `foo.txt`. Including the notion that it can 'run out' (which a keyboard never would).

Hence, when you write `nextLine()`, that's **not** the same as telling scanner: Please get me everything until the user hits the enter key.

No, it's: Get me everything until a newline symbol shows up in the stream. **if** `System.in` is the keyboard, one way to get a newline symbol is to hit enter. Another is to hit CMD+V or whatever you use to paste data into the terminal, and that data contains newline symbols. There is literally no way for `Scanner` to differentiate between those two things. Hence, there is no method to go: "Get me all text until the user hits enter". Because how would that method work? An enterpress looks identical to a newline in the pasted data. The signalling of 'okay, that was all I wanted to enter, please go ahead and process it' needs to be part of the data. If it's not 'newline symbol' (because you want to capture multi-paragraph stuff) then you'll have to come up with something else instead.

Separately, `nextLine()` is a broken method you should never use. It does exactly what its spec says it does, but what that is is not what you think it is. Instead, it's something quite useless. Scanner will dutifully continue to have `nextLine()` be this useless thing that has all sorts of surprising (read: unwanted) interactions with all the other `.next` operations on scanner.

Instead, use `.next()` if you want string input, and set the delimiter if the default delimiter (which is: Any whitespace, i.e. if you type 'Hello, World!' and hit enter, then the first 'token' is 'Hello,' and the second one is 'World!'. If you don't want that, set the delimiter to 'a newline' instead. For example).

With that in mind:

Here's one way to do it:

```
System.out.println("Paste your paragraph, then hit enter and type 'DONE' and hit enter again:");
scanner.useDelimiter("(?i)\\RDONE\\R");
String data = scanner.next();
System.out.println("Your paragraph contains: " + data.length() + " symbols.");
```

This tells the scanner that the 'thing that separates each token of input' is a newline, then the text DONE, then a newline (various OSes use different sequences of symbols for newline, `\\R` covers them all. `\n` probably works too, but `\\R` works on everything). The `(?i)` simply says that the `DONE` part is case insensitive.

The argument to `.useDelimiter` is a regex which is its own mini-programming language for describing regular grammars, which is why it may well strike you as really weird that you can stick `(?i)` in there and that this means 'case insensitive' somehow. We've really squeezed a mini-program inside those string quotes here.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful explanatio. Ill make sure to look into that "mini-programming" a bit further.
So Ive tried it now with your .useDelimiter version. And it almost works perfectly fine. The only issue (Im trying to fix) that I find is, that the last word of a line, and the next word of another line dont have Spaces anymore. Ill try to replace \n with \s or something :) But overall a quite educative solution you gave me! THANKS !!!

Answer (score 0):

For all the technical detail see the astonishing answer by @rzwitserloot. I assume what you actually wanted is to just be able to copy/paste a paragraph of text in the Console and display it right after. This can be done easily with this self-explanatory code snippet:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        StringBuilder paragraph = new StringBuilder();
        
        System.out.println("Some Paragraph");
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            paragraph.append(line).append('\n');
        }
        System.out.println("Paragraph: " + paragraph);
    }
}
```

Here we just append each line one after another.
If you want to read a multi-line paragraph from the console without a specific delimiter and without modifying the input, you can use a loop to continuously read lines until the user signals the end of input. This can be done by allowing the user to press a specific key combination (e.g., `Ctrl+D` or `Ctrl+Z`, depending on the operating system) to indicate the end of input.

Comment: or just `var paragraph = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));`

Comment: For some reason I see the "line" variable go up with each loop-iteration (in Debugger), but the Code just stops afterwards...
I copied your example (swapped out "paragraph" to "text")
Then after that my method:

System.print.outln(encrypt(text.toString());

It just ends the code after the whileLoop, though I see the loop storing all of the text, line by line, in StringBuilder"text"...